# unzipping text/csv files from .zip file in linux

Tags: linux, csv, redhat, unzip

I have zip files containing text (pipe delimited csv) that i receive daily. The file has to be bulk loaded to a database. When i unzip them using winrar or any tool in windows the file is valid. however, if i unzip it in Linux/redhat, the first half is valid csv but towards the second half the line breaks are misplaced. Some of the fields are even reordered.

I am running:

```
unzip -o zipfile.zip -d newfilepath
```

Tried:

```
unzip -oa zipfile.zip -d newfilepath
```

and

```
unzip -od zipfile.zip -d newfilepath
```

Comment: Try to install a newer version or just use another tool.

Comment: It seems that it is not treating all files as text. Have you tried `-aa`?

Comment: I've never had any problems. Maybe there is garbage data after the silly ^Z ? (-->> are the resulting file sizes a multiple of 512?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your zipfile is probably OK. You would see stranger results otherwise. 
Between linux and Windows I suspect line processing with different end of line characters.
Preprocess your csv with dos2unix or something similar.